# PowerShell Get the first date from event viewer for all entries

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to get the first logon time for each day from an array of dates obtained from Event Viewer.
I've already got the sorted array, with the information I'm interested in:

> TimeGenerated          Message
>   -------------          -------
>   10/10/2018 1:15:23 PM  An account was successfully logged on....
>   10/10/2018 12:02:55 PM An account was successfully logged on....
>   9/10/2018 3:23:43 PM   An account was successfully logged on....
>   9/10/2018 10:38:41 AM  An account was successfully logged on....
>   9/10/2018 10:20:40 AM  An account was successfully logged on....
>   8/10/2018 1:50:30 PM   An account was successfully logged on....
>   8/10/2018 1:48:19 PM   An account was successfully logged on....

What I'm hoping to get, is the first entry for each day:

> TimeGenerated          Message
>   -------------          -------
>   8/10/2018 1:48:19 PM   An account was successfully logged on....
>   9/10/2018 10:20:40 AM  An account was successfully logged on....
>   10/10/2018 12:02:55 PM An account was successfully logged on....

I suspect I need to sort all the entires by 'day' first, then find the latest full date from each filter, and as long as it's sorted, take the first one, but I can't filter this list by day.

```
$Logons = Get-EventLog Security -Source Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing | select TimeGenerated,Message | Where TimeGenerated -GT $StartDate | where Message -like "*An account was successfully logged on*"
```

The array allows me to select the unique days I'm interested in; `$Logons.timegenerated.day | sort -Unique` but I'm at a loss to find out how to match those to obtain the original values from that filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would group by day, and select first record from each day separately:

```
$events =  Get-EventLog Security -Source Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing

$events | group { $_.TimeGenerated.Date } | % { $_.Group | sort TimeGenerated | select -First 1 }
```